# Unable to open "Windows Network" to see other computers on LAN

Tags: samba, networking, sharing

I have my machine connected to our office LAN which has many other machines that use win XP, win 7 etc. Until a month or so ago, I was able to share files and folders with them, but now I can't even see what machines are there on my LAN, let alone access their files. I tried accessing a machine by its name, by opening `smb://machinename`, but that says

```
Error: Failed to retrieve share list from server
Please select another viewer and try again.
```

I tried restarting samba with `sudo service samba restart`, but that says `samba: unrecognized service`, but then samba is shown as *installed* in synaptic.

I am pretty much stuck on this. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the firewall. Disable it with

```
sudo ufw disable
```

did the trick.

Comment: I don't recommend doing this.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late answer but seems some people are still experiencing same problem. It is often happen that the problem lays not on client side (Ubuntu) but on server-side.

First of all I would suggest to check the firewall settings on Windows side. For example on Windows 7 I had to open TCP port 445 for SMB and UDP 137, 138 / TCP 137, 139 for NetBios API.

In order to do this go to Windows box and open:

```
Control Panel > Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules > Add Rule...
```

Add rules for each port mentioned above. Then you may try to connect from Ubuntu. In case you are still not able to connect - open the terminal and run commands to see shares

```
$ findsmb
$ smbtree
```

(hit enter when prompted for a password)

From the output of smbtree find the Windows station name and run

```
$ smbclient -L [NAME]
```

Since this moment you will be either connected to Share or will get an error code which will give you a hint about the origin of problem. For example, my error message was NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME (Windows computer name contained not allowed character) and the problem was fixed in 2 minutes.

Hope this information will be helpful.

Comment: findsmb: command not found.  sudo apt-get install findsmb: package not found

Comment: Probably you have a bug in your SMB package. Please see: [Bug #1362963](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1362963) for more details

Comment: its not `apt-get install findsmb` but `apt-get install smbclient`. In other words, the package you need is **smbclient** and not findsmb.

Comment: Well, at the moment of writing the answer, AFAIK, the most common/simple way to try first was `findsmb` - a nice Perl script which used to be part of the Samba suite, listing all subnet members responding to SMB name query. However, it looks like it's not actively supported anymore. Means you can still give a chance to `smbtree`, and then, as it was also mentioned by @DrunkenPoney - use the `smbclient` against entries you found (see his comment above for proper installation instructions in case `smbclient` is missing on your system)

Comment: This one should be the correct answer. It works for me

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can try viewing network in nautilus with `network:///` in nautilus location bar. As for restarting samba server I think try replacing samba in your service command with smb or smbd. Or try using machine ip rather than machine name.

Comment: The `network:///` shows me one entry, "Windows Network" and opening it fails with the error "Unable to mount location". Getting the IP address is not always practical, as the machine is in the other corner of this huge office :)

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1082148  May be you could try instructions from this forum

Comment: Oh yeah, on post on that thread mentions the firewall, which turned out to be my problem. damn! Thanks a lot, problem solved :).

Answer (score 0):

**That is a terrible and unsafe solution to completely turn off your firewall**.

Better one? Install gufw and add SAMBA sharing if you do not know how to manually configure your firewall. ;)

[image: Firewall configured]